# MS Application Insights What Client side code to use to set Application Version

Tags: azure-application-insights

I want to be able to segment Application Insights Data by application version.

Setting the Application Version attribute that gets associated with server-side telemetry data can be done in a TelemetryInitializer like so:

```
telemetry.Context.Component.Version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

How do you do the equivalent on the client side?  I'm finding that none of my client side data has an ApplicationVersion associated with it while the server side data does.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it with the following code:

```
window.appInsights.context.application.ver = "version";
window.appInsights.context.application.build = "build";
```

Comment: The answer above is apparently for the JavaScript SDK. Is there a way to define this information in the configuration?